# Forge viewer error with zoom and selection

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, forge

I have a problem with the forge viewer, Autodesk.Viewing.MultiViewerFactory(). When we click on an element we have programmed it to zoom. But when you zoom the selection, it no longer works as well as before the zoom. The highlight and selection are shifted a bit. As a result, you try to select one object and end up selecting another. It is a real problem that we need to solve with the viewer.

Comment: Could you please provide more information? What are the exact steps to reproduce this issue? Perhaps some screenshots indicating the problem?